# How do I ignore nested NPM dependency?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to ignore a specific dependency of one of your dependencies? Say I install module `A` which internally depends on `B`, and I want to ignore `B` and not install it when I do install `A`.

(The reason why I want this is because I know I would never use the bits of code from `A` that uses `B` so I want to reduce the size of node_modules).

Let's say we have:

```
// module A
exports.B = require('module-B');
exports.C = require('module-C');
```

When I `npm install A`, I know that I will only ever want to use `C`, so I want to ignore `module-B` from being installed.

Comment: I doubt it, most bundlers these days do a pretty good job of excluding code that isn't used.

Comment: @James this is a different topic. I basically want to `npm install` in a way that I know it will break part of my code.

Comment: That would be a very unsafe feature if it existed, don't you think @Kousha? It runs against the idea that a package is something you install without requiring knowledge of its internal workings.You would need a very intimate understanding of package A to be sure your software wouldn't fail at some unexpected point. And forget about updates! What you can do is use the --no-optional argument to prevent all optional dependencies of a package from being installed, though it's clearly not the solution you're looking for.

Comment: If this is a server or a local script, what's the big deal with letting the unused dependent module get installed.  It's just a small amount of disk space just sitting there.  Not doing anything.  Not slowing anything down.  Not taking memory if it's never loaded.  Just ignore it.  It sounds like you're trying to do some unnecessary and pre-mature optimization.

Comment: @Kousha perhaps, but the point is I highly doubt NPM would promote such a destructive feature, it's very much the exception to the rule. It would most likely cause more bugs and headaches than anything else.

Comment: @seesharper makes sense. I was wondering if it is possible. And the reason why I care is because of AWS Lambda limits. Wanting to reduce the total size as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ***can***, by using [NPM's local paths feature](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths) (in NPM >2.0.0).

Whether you ***should*** or not is a different matter...

Might go like this:

1. Create a dummy local package:

   - Create an `index.js` or equivalent, that simply exports something that matches the type or keys the real package uses. For example, if the real package exports an object containing a function called `someFunc` and an object `someObj`, then you might export something like `{ someFunc: () => {}, someObj: {} }`, so that files don't crash on, for example, `const { someFunc } = require('unwanted-nested-dep')
   - In its `package.json`, give it a name that communicates what you're doing and why:

   > ```
   > {
   >     "name": "skip-this-dependency",
   >     "description": "This is a dummy package to prevent unwanted nested dependencies from being installed",
   > ```
2. Then, in your main `package.json`, add an entry for each unwanted nested dep that points to this; something like this last line:

   > ```
   > "dependencies": {
   >   "async": "^2.4.2",
   >   "pumpify": "^1.3.0",
   >   "unwanted-nested-dep": "file:../skip-this-dependency"
   > }
   > ```

But be warned, **there will be side effects of doing this**!

For example, you might try to prevent future errors by pinning the version number of the dependency that requires the unwanted nested dep... but you could still get errors if an update do a different dependency adds your skipped nested dep as a dependency, uses it, and expects it to work.

This is a crude, blunt option to avoid using if at all possible. Usually you should find another way to solve the underlying problem (e.g. fork or replace the direct dependency, or use npm cache or prune etc).